# how i can make a word limit in textarea

Tags: php, forms

i have little knowledge on javascript, so can you tell me
how i can make a word limit in this below textarea

`<textarea name="notes" "rows="4" cols="40"></textarea>`

Comment: Word or character? Also, are you trying to enforce this in PHP or via JavaScript? Either way, please put more effort into writing your questions.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [word limit in textarea - problem](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4511186/word-limit-in-textarea-problem)

Answer (score 0):

use this function

```
<script>
     function textAreaCounter(field,cntfield,maxlimit) 
    {

     if (field.value.length > maxlimit) 
     field.value = field.value.substring(0, maxlimit); 
     else cntfield.value = maxlimit - field.value.length;
    }

</script>
<form name="frmlist" id="frmlist" method="post">
<div>
                <textarea rows="8" cols="70" name="description" id="description" onFocus="textAreaCounter(document.frmlist.description,document.frmlist.descriptionCount,1000)" onKeyDown="textAreaCounter(document.frmlist.description,document.frmlist.descriptionCount,1000)" onKeyUp="textAreaCounter(document.frmlist.description,document.frmlist.descriptionCount,1000)"></textarea>
                <br>
                <br>
                <em>Characters remaining:</em>
                <input type="text" name="descriptionCount" id="descriptionCount" readonly="" size="5" value="<?php if(isset($frmdata['descriptionCount'])){echo $frmdata['descriptionCount']; } else{ echo '1000'; }?>" >
            </div></form>
```

Comment: if any answer solves your problem, then accept answer by checking right sign.

Comment: but i can't install it with my form

Answer (score 0):

Can be done easily with a bit of javascript. Put your textarea in a form:

```
<form name="userform">
    <textarea name="notes" "rows="4" cols="40" onKeyDown="limitInput();">
    </textarea>
</form>
```

Add this function to your javascript:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function limitInput() {
    var limitField = document.userform.notes;
    if (limitField.value.length > 10) {
        limitField.value = limitField.value.substring(0, 10);
    }
}
</script>
```

Comment: how i should install it with my form